# Update table data using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to have a table with 5 rows being updated periodically. Currently, I have it running as shown [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musale/z60fho1u/).

`index.html`

```
<table id="attack-table" class="table table-sm table-dark table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Source Country</th>
  <th>Target Country</th>
  <th>Date Created</th>
  <th>Attack Type</th>
  <th>Parameter</th>
</tr>
```

`index.js`

```
(function() {
function updateTable(alerts) {
const table = d3.select("#attack-table");
const tableBody = table.append("tbody");

tableBody
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(alerts)
  .enter()
  .append("tr")
  .selectAll("td")
  .data(function(row, i) {
    return [{
        column: "Source Country",
        value: row.country
      },
      {
        column: "Target Country",
        value: row.targetCountry
      },
      {
        column: "Date Created",
        value: row.dateCreated
      },
      {
        column: "Attack Type",
        value: row.analyzerType
      },
      {
        column: "Parameter",
        value: row.requestString
      }
    ];
  })
  .enter()
  .append("td")
  .attr("class", "small")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
}
const alerts = [{
  "analyzerType": "VNC(vnclowpot)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "RU",
  "countryName": "Russian Federation",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "25.66669999999999",
  "destLng": "-100.3167",
  "id": "48a140b7df45cdb824eb898b3647f9b9",
  "requestString": "",
  "sourceLat": "55.75219999999999",
  "sourceLng": "37.6156",
  "targetCountry": "MX"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "VNC(vnclowpot)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "RU",
  "countryName": "Russian Federation",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.10249999999999",
  "destLng": "8.629899999999992",
  "id": "cdf7b9ebff8e49073bc54998c32542f3",
  "requestString": "",
  "sourceLat": "55.75219999999999",
  "sourceLng": "37.6156",
  "targetCountry": "DE"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "Network(honeytrap)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "-",
  "countryName": "-",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.708021",
  "destLng": "7.129191",
  "id": "06f701c097bc0df0c091ad0e74272377",
  "requestString": "Attack on port 5900/tcp",
  "sourceLat": "50.708021",
  "sourceLng": "7.129191",
  "targetCountry": "PIR"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "Network(Dionaea)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "NL",
  "countryName": "Netherlands",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.708021",
  "destLng": "7.129191",
  "id": "86d45dd8856c95fe4c9d950ac6075ff3",
  "requestString": "Attack on port 5060/udp",
  "sourceLat": "52.38239999999999",
  "sourceLng": "4.899499999999989",
  "targetCountry": "PIR"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "Network(Dionaea)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "US",
  "countryName": "United States",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.708021",
  "destLng": "7.129191",
  "id": "d186782a94d472b8b967edf748fffe47",
  "requestString": "Attack on port 3306/tcp",
  "sourceLat": "40.498099999999994",
  "sourceLng": "-74.3194",
  "targetCountry": "PIR"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "Network(Dionaea)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "NL",
  "countryName": "Netherlands",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.708021",
  "destLng": "7.129191",
  "id": "d6447b9b4883a26e08f8c302c3e3efea",
  "requestString": "Attack on port 5060/udp",
  "sourceLat": "52.38239999999999",
  "sourceLng": "4.899499999999989",
  "targetCountry": "PIR"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "VNC(vnclowpot)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "RU",
  "countryName": "Russian Federation",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.10249999999999",
  "destLng": "8.629899999999992",
  "id": "f847fd75a20a9a89d92c75ee34a1f704",
  "requestString": "",
  "sourceLat": "55.75219999999999",
  "sourceLng": "37.6156",
  "targetCountry": "DE"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "VNC(vnclowpot)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "-",
  "countryName": "-",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.708021",
  "destLng": "7.129191",
  "id": "eaf7035d34072636afe55014140dffcd",
  "requestString": "",
  "sourceLat": "50.708021",
  "sourceLng": "7.129191",
  "targetCountry": "-"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "Webpage",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "US",
  "countryName": "United States",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.708021",
  "destLng": "7.129191",
  "id": "b55ab3597ea3cdc794b4fcdc11eb590e",
  "requestString": "/gnu/servlet/1220/base.php?eval=",
  "sourceLat": "42.813500000000005",
  "sourceLng": "-70.886",
  "targetCountry": "PIR"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "VNC(vnclowpot)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "RU",
  "countryName": "Russian Federation",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "50.10249999999999",
  "destLng": "8.629899999999992",
  "id": "7be4654b45d39543e6a60f9cecf76b85",
  "requestString": "",
  "sourceLat": "55.75219999999999",
  "sourceLng": "37.6156",
  "targetCountry": "DE"
},
{
  "analyzerType": "VNC(vnclowpot)",
  "clientDomain": true,
  "country": "RU",
  "countryName": "Russian Federation",
  "dateCreated": "2018-07-13 19:29:42",
  "destLat": "25.66669999999999",
  "destLng": "-100.3167",
  "id": "1ac340048643fb3e4f0891828bbe74d2",
  "requestString": "",
  "sourceLat": "55.75219999999999",
  "sourceLng": "37.6156",
  "targetCountry": "MX"
}
]
// this is done periodically in the app with diff data points
/* setInterval(updateTable.bind(null,alerts), 1000) */
updateTable(alerts)
})();
```

What I would like to achieve is updating the 5 rows data and not stacking them below each other. I'm new to d3 js so an understandable solution would really help me understand the update and exit concepts of d3.

Comment: What do you mean by updating the 5 rows of data? Do you mean you want to select 5 rows and then update the values in them maintaining their position in the table? Or do you mean you want to add 5 rows to the top of the table? Or do you mean you only want to display 5 rows, and then update to the next rows in the array on a function call? I got confused because in your JS fiddle you have more than 5 rows of data.

Comment: @REEE what I mean is, I create the initial 5 rows (which I assume the code does) then I update the values, maintaining their position in the table (which at the moment, stacks the values to be updated in rows below the initial 5 rows - which appears in the fiddle).

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, give me two seconds I'll write it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update d3 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871044/how-to-update-d3-table)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to have the table reflect the latest dataset each time your `updateTable()` function is executed, then you could just remove the `tbody` before redrawing the table on each update. For example, you could add something like the following to the beginning of your `updateTable()` function:

```
d3.select("#attack-table tbody").remove();
```

As an aside, d3 is probably overkill for building a table with data that refreshes periodically (but maybe you are planning on more bells and whistles than indicated here).

Answer (score 0):

First things first, here's a working codepen (hopefully this is what you wanted): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajdbBZ?editors=0011

So the first thing you needed to do was load 5 rows worth of data when originally creating the rows, I did this by using [.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and a variable for the start position along your 'alerts' array and how many records you were going to fetch in 'increment':

```
var startPos = 0,
    increment = 5;
function generateTable(alerts) {
  const table = d3.select("#attack-table");
  const tableBody = table.append("tbody");

  tableBody
    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(alerts.slice(startPos, (startPos + increment)))
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row, i) { ...
```

To update the values in the rows generated from the above function, I created another function called 'next', which loads the next set (+1 records). This was done by selecting all 'tr' row, setting the data to the new slice of data and then using [.each](http://d3indepth.com/selections/) I called a function on every 'td' cell to change the data values and the text. You can see this here:

```
function next(alerts) {
  if ((startPos + increment) < alerts.length) {
    startPos++;

    d3.selectAll('tbody')
      .selectAll('tr')
      .data(alerts.slice(startPos, (startPos + increment)))
      .each(function (d) {
        var self = d3.select(this);
            self.selectAll("td")
                .data(function(row, i) {
                  return [
                    {
                      column: "Source Country",
                      value: row.country
                    },
                    {
                      column: "Target Country",
                      value: row.targetCountry
                    },
                    {
                      column: "Date Created",
                      value: row.dateCreated
                    },
                    {
                      column: "Attack Type",
                      value: row.analyzerType
                    },
                    {
                      column: "Parameter",
                      value: row.requestString
                    }
                  ];
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                  return d.value; 
                });
        })
  }
}
```